# Rails action Mailer raise_delivery_errors, how does it works? How to detect bounces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Rails 4.2.0 application which sends lots of mails, it's a elearning platfrom.

At the moment I have problems with bounces, Lots of the Mails coming back because the Mail-Adresses aren't valid.

One way is to solve the problem manually, starting deleting them from Database. But thats not suitable because there are about 10000 Users registered.

Now my questsion is what is

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

exactly? what does it do? and how do I get response from this?

Does the `mail()` method got a return value where I can see If a mail was send or not?

And are there methods or best practices to detect with the actionmailer, if a mail is delivered or not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If set to `false`, mail will silently catch and ignore any exceptions raised through attempting to deliver an email. [Reference](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mikel/mail/Mail/Message:raise_delivery_errors).

In production it is good to set it to `false`, because otherwise failed email will throw an error to your end user.

In development definitely set it to `true`.

Take a look at [this gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail).

Among other features there is a method specifically to check [if mail was  `bounced`](https://github.com/mikel/mail#getting-error-reports-from-an-email).

Comment: I run the mailings with cronjobs where are the errors shown then? Ind are there other ways to detect bounces?

Comment: By the way, today, Rails Action Mailer uses the [Mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail), the `bounced?` method is available in Rails.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it's better to set it to `true` in production because you should send your emails in background jobs and sending the email will be retried if an error is raised.

```rb
  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
```

And set it to `false` in development as the initial rails setup says, you `Don't care if the mailer can't send.`

```rb
  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
```

From `rails new b` in `Rails 7.0.2.3`